# Small group tabletop

Tags: game-recommendation

I'm looking for a table top game that can be played with 2 people and a dm/gm without limiting what can be done game wise or cause them to have to play multiple hero characters (talking to themselves isn't fun to listen to).

I kind of like how warhammer 40k armies battle style where they can be a commander of their own squads in combat. I could see giving them more "points" for their armies to account for less people playing or what not, but it would be nice to have an out of fight roleplay experience to go with it where the armies are their own men with their own lives outside the battle.

I don't just want a tabletop wargame experience though, I'm looking for a system that can deal with outside encounter (intelligence gathering, crafting, skill checks, etc) while still having a combat that is engaging for 2 people (I want bigger combats at low levels that dont involve throwing tons of 1hp minions at the characters, and allow them to use skills that are meant for outside combat in combat in interesting ways.

Is there anything like this out, or am i going to have to piece together multiple tabletops with some homebrew to fill in the cracks?

Edit: Upon looking more into it and SevenSidedDie's response I really cant think of how to narrow this down anymore. Thanks for your time mods, and I'll continue to look this up on my own, if you could remove this post (haven't figured out how yet) I would be grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Role-playing Games! As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Comment: Welcome, white-flare. Take a look at our sys rec FAQ linked above. There are many many games that can be played with 2 PCs, and we need to know more about what your requirements are. Setting, desired interactions, genre, complexity, all of these things can help us answer your question. As phrased currently, the standard set of "FATE / Ars Magica / No, you can do this with D&D" all apply. We need a way to differentiate a good answer from a bad answer. I'm happy to reopen this question after a bit of editing.

Comment: Short version: what kind of stories do you want to tell? What kind of challenges do you want to overcome? What kind of world do you want to play in?

Comment: If all you want is a system as a framework for the bits of roleplaying of individuals between wargame battles, then nearly *any* system will do. It's not like you'll be using it for carefully-balance encounters, since most of your fighty time (in real time) will be taken up by the wargaming, so you only really need a character stats and rolling system. Pick one and go play!

Comment: Your latest edit still doesn't narrow down the possibilities at all. FYI, there are *literally* thousands of RPGs--[there are 4077 as of right now listed in RPGGeek's database alone](http://rpggeek.com/browse/rpg). Most RPGs in that list of thousands would give you skills and engaging, flexible-difficulty combat. How can we possibly choose *one* that would be the "right answer"? If you simply don't have any further needs to narrow it down, then we really aren't able to help and you'll be just fine picking one at pretty much random.

Comment: You really can do this in D&D 3.5e, Pathfinder, FATE, GURPS and almost all  the others. One on ones are possible, even - just tune the challenges to match their abilities. (That's one player character, possibly with a GM NPC, not one player controlling a full party) You don't need to find a whole new system for this; all you need if anything is to find some advice on how to run games for just 2 players (or one). Good luck with this and have fun!